# input type button enable/disable attribute

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

How to disable/enable button depending on whenever `itemToAdd` javascript property is empty or not

```
<input type="text" data-bind='value:itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
            <input type="button" data-bind="click:$parent.addItem" value="add" />
```

[here's jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mk_yo/M2xDF/35/)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an `enable` binding in knockout for this:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click:$parent.addItem, enable: itemToAdd" value="add" />
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M2xDF/36/